# What is the scenario for getting error "dial tcp xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:3306: connect: connection refused" and how to avoid this error

Tags: mysql, go, error-handling

I have a api which is calling the sql connection. This is sql connection to some remote server. While performing a query I am getting error "dial tcp xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:3306: connect: connection refused"

Sql connection code

```
func ConnectToMysqlDB(dbUser, dbPassword, dbHost, dbName string) *sql.DB {
    connstr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s", dbUser, dbPassword, dbHost, "3306", dbName)
    var err error
    log.Println("Carrying mysql query", connstr)
    dB, err := sql.Open("mysql", connstr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error connection to mysql [%v] ..!!", err)
    }
    log.Print("mysql initialized ..!!")
    return dB
}
```

Query function

```
func GetUserIDs(dB *sql.DB, users []string) []int {
    var newUsers []int
    var newUser int

    query := "SELECT id FROM phplist_user_user WHERE foreignkey in (%s)"
    var usersStr string
    for _, val := range users {
        usersStr = usersStr + "'" + val + "'" + ","
    }
    usersStr = strings.TrimSuffix(usersStr, ",")

    query = fmt.Sprintf(query, usersStr)

    rows, err := dB.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error in query : [%v]", err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(&newUser)
        newUsers = append(newUsers, newUser)
    }

    return newUsers
}
```

what is the sceario where I am getting the error: Error in query : [dial tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306: connect: connection refused]

Comment: Note that `sql.Open` does not actually open the connection, it only prepares a connection pool for use. An attempt to establish a connection is made only once you try querying the db, or send a ping. So even if the `ConnectToMysqlDB` function successfully returns a `*sql.DB`, that does **not** mean that you can actually connect to the database. The possible reasons for *why* you are getting "connection refused" are many, common among them is that the remote server does not listen on port 3306, or the user-pass combo is incorrect.

Comment: ... [`sql.Open`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17.8#Open): *"Open may just validate its arguments without creating a connection to the database. To verify that the data source name is valid, call Ping."*

Comment: @mkopriva for my scenario combo is correct and the remote server listen on port 3306 for small request body(50). But when Request Body size increases to 100 it causes this error. Is there a way to prevent high concurrency on sql.

Comment: Note that `'3306'` does not compile, you probably meant: `"3306"`. Also note that your SQL `query` is susceptible to sql injection attacks, you should use parameter placeholders instead of directly concatenating the raw input.

Comment: 'Connection refused' means nothing is listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. It has nothing to do with payload size whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents:

1. Validate if you are really connected to mysql using the Ping() method in sql.DB — however you must pay attention that some errors may be temporary. For instance if you have a network issue or a database “reboot” (high availability depends of many factors)
2. Check if you are using the right ip and port. Perhaps the database and application are in different networks or the database server binds more than one network card.

Also, Check if this helps
https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#allowcleartextpasswords